# ListBox scrolling

Tags: c#, listbox, scroll

When I remove item from `ListBox`, it's scrolling to selected item. If there's no item selected, then it's scrolling to top of the list. Is it possible to make it stay still when removing items?

I don't really need selecting items enabled, but even if I set selecting mode to none, it's scrolling to the top.

I'm using `listBox1.Items.Remove(...)` method for removing items.

I tried to get `AutoScrollOffset` before removing and then after removing set it the same value of X and Y as it was before, but it doesn't work.

I put `Thread.Sleep` and `MessageBox` right after method that removes item and it looks like it scrolls before my message is displayed, so it must be Items.Remove causing the scroll.

My ListBox code looks like that:

```
private ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
this.listBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.listBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
this.listBox1.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
this.listBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(238)));
this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.listBox1.IntegralHeight = false;
this.listBox1.ItemHeight = 16;
this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 6);
this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
this.listBox1.ScrollAlwaysVisible = true;
this.listBox1.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.SelectionMode.None;
this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 388);
this.listBox1.TabIndex = 0;
this.listBox1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.listBox1_DrawItem);
```

in `listBox1_DrawItem()` is just `DrawBackground()`, `Graphics.DrawString()`, `DrawFocusRectangle()`, and nothing else that could matter.

Maybe there is some property I don't know about or maybe I need to install update or something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
int tempTopIndex = listBox1.TopIndex;
listBox1.Items.Remove(yourItem);
listBox1.TopIndex = tempTopIndex;
```

Comment: that's great and the simplest :) I was thinking about using IndexFromPoint and then calculate SelectedIndex and set it after I remove item, but now it doesn't matter...